# contenteditable - backspace and delete removes comments

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have the below snippet on my application. In the browser, if I use backspace or delete keys inside the contenteditable div, it removes the comments adjacent to the text, which I need to prevent.

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#editedHTML").text($("#myEditor").html());

  $("#save").click(function() {
    $("#editedHTML").text($("#myEditor").html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myEditor" contenteditable="true">
  Hello World (press backspace after this)
  <!-- This should not be removed -->
</div>
<br>

<button id="save">
  Save
</button>
<br>Content to be saved:
<div id="editedHTML">
</div>
```

Comment: You're assigning the content of your editor to editedHTML on save, so it will mirror whatever is in there...

Comment: @OliverJ90, Yes. but my `editedHTML` should have the comments in `myEditor`. But they are removed when I backspace the `)`.